# Sources of yearly electricity consumption data for India?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, energy, india, open-source

I am looking for yearly or monthly **electricity consumption data** for India for the period 2013-2020. Is there any website that provides these kind of data? The data set should be at the District level at least (748 districts in total).

Answer (score 0):

You can get electricity generation data and it's monthly report on central electricity authority, India website while it is hard to get electricity consumption data.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a platform named "YouData" that has proven incredibly helpful to me in finding datasets for training AI systems. They are still in their "Beta testing" phase, though!

Check out their platform for obtaining free datasets. https://youdata-webapp.vercel.app/home.

Feel free to explore and let me know if you find it as valuable as I did! Happy researching!